# Помогите вытянуть строку из ресурса в метод

Tags: java, android

помогите с этим методом setError(). В приложении 2 ЯЗЫКА и хочется чтобы он при его смене менялся везде, но вот не могу заставить этот метод меняться edit1.setError("бла бла");... подскажите новичку в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string.xml`  с Русскими строками кладите в `values-ru`, с неРусскими в `values-en`

```
setError(getString(R.string.error))
```